# como podria obtener datos de una base de datos mysql, con javascript y meterlos en un array?

Tags: javascript, json

Me explico mejor, tengo un programa en javascript, en el cual tengo que generar eventos con fullcalendar, he pensado que la mejor manera(o, almenos, la que me va a funcionar) es haciendo en javascript una funcion donde me obtenga los datos de la base de datos, inserte cada columna de la base de datos dentro de una array distinta y despues con un bucle if ir separando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Si te quieres conectar a una base de datos de MySQL con JavaScript, puedes usar `NodeJS` y una librería llamada `mysql`. Puedes crear consultas y obtener los resultados como un arreglo de registros
>
> [Respuesta de stack overflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18339285/12812277)

Si sigues el enlace de esa respuesta encontrarás que al final la persona usaba el modelo clásico de JavaScript para el front end y el back end con PHP por lo que no encontrarás mas detalle al respecto.

---

Esto lo encontre un tutorial de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp) que te ayudará mas a fondo en lo que buscas y básicamente estos son los pasos a seguir

### Instala el controlador de MySQL

```sh
C:\Users\Your Name>npm install mysql
```

`Node.js` puede utilizar este modulo para manipular la base de datos de MySQL:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
```

### Crea una conección

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

### Consulta la base de datos

El objeto `con` del ejemplo anterior, tiene un método para consultar la base de datos:

```js
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Result: " + result);
  });
});
```

El método `query` toma un `sentencia sql` como parámetro y devuelve el resultado.